# "I hear it from..." Different uses of present tense

Tags: past-tense, semantics, present-tense

> Americans are angry. **I hear it from** the former factory workers who lost their jobs to other countries because of bad trade deals, the veterans who wait months to see a doctor at Veterans Hospital and the small-business owners who..."

How should I understand the meaning that carries "I hear it from"?

1. As a present tense meaning that I heard it in the past, I hear now and it will be the same in the future, that is: "I always hear it from..."
2. As a present tense using a past reference, meaning "I heard that Americans are angry, and I heard it from former factory workers..."
3. something else, but what exactly?

By the way, this is not an oral speech, but an opinion, an Op-ed to be exactly.

Answer (score 1):

So, this from a Trump speech, but what he means is "I'm hearing". He has heard and continues to hear the same thing. I heard [something] and I continue to hear [something/it] again and again.

I hear from my sister [all the time]. I hear things, meaning I'm listening.

Comment: *I hear things* does not mean *I'm listening*.

Comment: @Drew, if I said "I hear you", what would that be saying?

Comment: You can hear without listening, just as you can see without watching. And you can listen without hearing.

Comment: @Drew, you can. But if you're taking someone's word, if they say they hear, you're begging their sincerity by saying they're not listening.

Comment: John, actually, this is not a Donald Trump's speech. This is a Chris Collins OP-ED Contributor.

Comment: No, problem. But I think that's a good point, because if it were a Donald Trump's speech I would interpret it as: "As I hear it every time from Americans I can affirm they are angry". But as an opinion in favor of Trump  I would interpret it as: "I say Americans are angry because I have heard it (listened, seen, etc) from these people"

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible interpretations in this particular case.  Looking at this sentence out of context, one can interpret "it" as referring to anger, or angry words: "Americans are angry. I hear [anger] from the former factory workers..."

But if you look at the original quote in context, another interpretation is possible: "it" may be referring *forward* to the phrase "enough is enough" which appears at the end of the paragraph.  Normally, the word "it" is used to refer to something mentioned immediately previously, but it is also possible to use it to refer ahead in one's writing, and considering the whole paragraph that this quote came from, I think that was this author's intention:

> Americans are angry. I hear **it** from the former factory workers who lost their jobs to other countries because of bad trade deals, the veterans who wait months to see a doctor at a Veterans Affairs hospital and the small-business owners who are struggling to stay afloat because of the Affordable Care Act’s crippling regulations. The professional politicians they trusted and supported have repeatedly sold out our country in favor of special interests and the status quo. Finally, millions of Americans are saying, “**Enough is enough**.”  (http://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/16/opinion/the-case-for-donald-trump.html)

Comment: FailedTheTuringTest, thank you, I didn't consider that "it" could refer to that last part of the paragraph. However, does the form of the present tense of the verb"hear" refers to present meaning (habitual) or does it has a reference to the past (something that one heard in the past but still is operative, e.g. "I hear (that) poor Mr. Simpson has gone into hospital")?